# The search friendly industry term for 'Biomedical device' or 'medical device'

Tags: english-to-german, terminology, technical-terminology

I'm an American engineer living in Germany, and I'm seeking work on sites like Jobbörse and Monster.de.

I'm not sure what the industry accepted term for "Biomedical device" or "Medical device" is - when referring to things like medical device implants, prosthetics with embedded microprocessors, medical accessories like cochlear implants or insulin pumps, etc. Things that would use embedded-C as a programming language.

I'm seeking the correct term that industry or academic employers would use as keyword when searching on job sites.

Different translation engines have suggested  ...

> Biomedizinischen Vorrichtung
>   Biomedizinische Geräte
>   Medizintechniker (medical device engineer)

Comment: I would probably search for either more general (*Medizintechnik*, to find  actual employers) or more specific (*Medizinische Informatik* or *Medizininformatiker* to find open positions) terms

Comment: Do you search for the translation of "Biomedical device" or do you search for a term of the job you are looking for?

Comment: @IQV *I'm seeking the correct term that industry or academic employers would use as keyword when searching on job sites.*

Comment: @tofro Überschrift: "The search friendly industry term for 'Biomedical device' or 'medical device'" - für mich ist die Frage ist nicht wirklich eindeutig.

Answer (score 2):

#### Medizingeräte

The EU and with them German and Austrian law regulates all products and devices that are used in a medical setting ([*Medizinprodukterichtlinie*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richtlinie_93/42/EWG_%C3%BCber_Medizinprodukte)).

Amongst these products technical devices ([*Medizingeräte*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medizinprodukt) or *medizinische Geräte*) are a subgroup, again regulated by law ([*Medizingeräteverordnung*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medizinger%C3%A4teverordnung)).

#### Medizintechnik

The science with developing or maintaining such devices is called *[Medizintechnik](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medizintechnik)*, hence a person working in this field is a *Medizintechniker*.

Answer (score 0):

When i was looking for work in that field i used terms like "Medizintechnik" (= medical technology)or "Medizinprodukte" (= medical devices). "Medizintechniker" could be suitable, but this can also refer to someone with a cerification for the maintenance of medical devices (usually larger ones like CT or MRI systems or other clinical equipment) and might be less relevant if you are looking for work in the design of medical devices.